# Kindle Fire HD on-screen keyboard on Nexus 5

Tags: keyboard, nexus-5, amazon-kindle-fire

I have found the keyboard on the Kindle Fire HD to be one of the best mobile device on-screen keyboards I have used and am wondering if it's available on any other devices?

Much like other android alternative keyboards such as SwiftKey, is there a version similar to the Kindle keyboard that I would be able to install on my Nexus 5?

Thanks.

Device: Nexus 5

OS: Android 4.4.4

Rooted: Yes

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're looking for [this](http://www.mediafire.com/?lqwxmy4ccb6php7)?
This is the stock Kindle Fire HD keyboard.And this is the actual [link](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1941571) if you're concerned. Don't follow the instructions mentioned on the link.It is only to replace the system keyboard.

Comment: It would be better if you also state the name of the app (LatinIME.apk). Also, avoid direct link to file-sharing site and use more credible site such as Google Play Store, XDA Forum, GitHub, etc. We discourage file-sharing site unless it's 100% safe, which we can't ensure.

Comment: Andrew, thanks for your suggestion.Had edited the answer earlier through stack exchange android but changes did not reflect.So edited using desktop.